# Get all nodes as new Elements without tree structure

Tags: xml, xslt

I know the question is a bit unspecific but I didn't know how to word it better. Here's my question: I have an XML-Document and want to convert it into another XML-Document using XSL but without the tree structure, so that all the elements are displayed as a list. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
<name>
    <given_name>Peter</given_name>
    <surname>Pan</surname>
    <title>PhD</title>
</name>
<contactdata>
    <email>peter.pan@gmail.com</email>
    <office>
        <building>B10</building>
        <room>016</room>
    </office>
    <phone type="office">01234567</phone>
</contactdata>
<organization>
    <group>Something Cool</group>
    <department>Awesome Stuff!!!</department>
</organization>
```

Will be transformated into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shallow>
  <person />
  <person-name />
  <person-name-given_name />
  <person-name-surname />
  <person-name-title />
  <person-contactdata />
  <person-contactdata-email />
  <person-contactdata-office />
  <person-contactdata-office-building />
  <person-contactdata-office-room />
  <person-contactdata-phone />
  <person-organization />
  <person-organization-group />
  <person-organization-department />
 </shallow>
```

My code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <shallow>
  <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:with-param name="predecessor" select="local-name()"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  </shallow>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:param name="predecessor"/>
  <xsl:element name="{$predecessor}"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:with-param name="predecessor" select="concat($predecessor, '-', local-name())"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it will only iterate up to the first child of everything and the output is not quite right.....

I'll appreciate any help, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does iterate properly; it is the name of the output element that is not computed properly.

You just need to change :

```
<xsl:element name="{$predecessor}"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:element name="{concat($predecessor, '-', local-name())}"/>
```

PS: the text contained in the tags is also output, this might be corrected with this additional modification (if needed):

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:with-param name="predecessor" select="concat($predecessor, '-', local-name())"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

With all these modification, here my output so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shallow>
    <person-name/>
   <person-name-given_name/>
   <person-name-surname/>
   <person-name-title/>
    <person-contactdata/>
   <person-contactdata-email/>
   <person-contactdata-office/>
   <person-contactdata-office-building/>
   <person-contactdata-office-room/>
   <person-contactdata-phone/>
    <person-organization/>
   <person-organization-group/>
   <person-organization-department/>
</shallow>
```

Comment: ah! Awesome!!! No wonder I didn't find the error when I looked for it at the wrong spot^^ Thanks a lot!